# How do I add a double-click event listener to tray icon using SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I have an SWT tray icon which I've created with the following snippet of code:

```
    itmTrayItem = new TrayItem(trySysTray, SWT.NONE);
    itmTrayItem.setToolTipText("My App");
    itmTrayItem.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            mnuPopup.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Right clicking on the tray icon brings up a context menu. I'd like to add a double-click event to the tray icon so that when the icon is double-clicked I perform some action. How can I do this?

I haven't understood how I was use the mouse listener as I've been finding some parts of the SWT docs lacking in examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the SWT.DefaultSelection event, it may do the trick

Comment: Hi Gorkem. I'm not sure how to go about this. Would you be a able to elaborate a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I found some examples. I'll try it. http://www.javadocexamples.com/org/eclipse/swt/SWT/SWT.DefaultSelection.html